# about jquery switching parent element increase

Tags: jquery, this, parent

```
$(".user_img").click(function() {
if ($(".user-insert-image").css("display") == 'none') {
    $(".user-upload-image").hide();
    $(".user-insert-image").show();
} else {
    $(".user-insert-image").hide();
    $(".user-upload-image").show();
} });
```

Only the first element is available, Add elements not available

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWBNg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are generating the elements dynamically. You should delegate the event:

```
$('.main').on('click', '.user_img', function() {
```

Also you need to use `this` keyword, your current logic hides/shows all the elements.

```
$('.main').on('click', ".user_img", function() {
    var $this = $(this).parent();
    if ($this.hasClass('user-insert-image')) {
        $this.hide().prev().show()
    } else {
        $this.hide().next().show()
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dUQF6/

Comment: thanks man but the first one have some bug, you can fix this?